# Border of div invisible

Tags: html, css, border

I make scale for schedule.

Intermediate lines are not visible unless I specify the size of div.
without lines:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/x1h9ape3/2/
```

with lines:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/x1h9ape3/3/`
```

I need width=100%.

How to show lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: flex` on your `sch_row_hour` class.

https://jsfiddle.net/3urqwtkn/

Comment: I insert <div> as day column, but it on bottom(

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: Like this
http://i.imgur.com/OgKywOt.png
I make this in SVG with JS

Comment: I don't find changes